# How React hot toaster can be customised?

Tags: reactjs, react-hot-toast

Maybe it is a naive question, but I do not get this syntax, why not a component is returned here?

```js
// src/@core/styles/libs/react-hot-toast

const ReactHotToast = styled(Box)<BoxProps>(({ theme }) => {
    // ** Hook & Var
    const { settings } = useSettings()
    const { layout, navHidden } = settings

    return {
        '& > div': {
            left: `${theme.spacing(6)} !important`,
            right: `${theme.spacing(6)} !important`,
            bottom: `${theme.spacing(6)} !important`,
            top:
                layout === 'horizontal' && !navHidden
                    ? '139px !important'
                    : '75px !important',
        },
        '& .react-hot-toast': {
            fontWeight: 400,
            borderRadius: 8,
            fontSize: '1rem',
            letterSpacing: '0.14px',
            boxShadow: theme.shadows[3],
            zIndex: theme.zIndex.snackbar,
            color: theme.palette.text.primary,
            background: theme.palette.background.paper,
            '&>:first-of-type:not([role])>:first-of-type': {
                width: 14,
                height: 14,
            },
        },
    }
})
```

And in `_app.tsx` it is loaded here, and passed

```js
// ** Styled Components
import ReactHotToast from 'src/@core/styles/libs/react-hot-toast'

//..

<ReactHotToast>
<Toaster
position={settings.toastPosition}
toastOptions={{ className: 'react-hot-toast' }}
/>
</ReactHotToast>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I might be wrong, but this is how I understand it:

> why not a component is returned here?

You have a component named `Box`;

You can style it with:

```js
const ReactHotToast = styled(Box)`
  /* some CSS here */
`;
```

here you only add CSS styles.

`styled` will return a component for you so there is no need to "a component" when using `styled`.

In your case, the engineer needed props from a custom hook `useSettings()`.

But what is `` styled(Box)`/* some CSS here */` ``? It's just a function call, but without brackets:

[image]

So you can also have:

```
const ReactHotToast = styled(Box)(({ theme }) => {
  // here probably, (need to check the implementation)
  // the styled-components is waiting for a return object
  // that will behave like a CSS style
  // so you return an object that has key '.react-hot-toast'
  // and you can use this className in the child components
})
```

In conclusion, this code probably was written because the engineer needed props from `useSettings()`;

I would suggest refactoring it and pass props from parent component,
maybe this could work

```js
const ReactHotToast = styled(Box)<BoxProps>`
  ${({theme, layout, navHidden}) => `
    & > div {
            left: `${theme.spacing(6)} !important`
    }
    & .react-hot-toast {
      /* other CSS here */
    }
  `}
`

const ReactHotToastContainer = ({children}) => {
  const { settings } = useSettings();
  const { layout, navHidden } = settings
  return <ReactHotToast layout={layout} navHidden={navHidden}>{children}</ReactHotToast>;
}
```